# Modifying individual text fields in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I have this variable whose length should always be 9 characters

```
PEPTIDE_SEQ="AAAAAAAAA"
```

Then i created the length variable as

```
len=9
```

What i want to do is to start from the PEPTIDE_SEQ and output to file a block like this:

```
AAAAAAAAA
CAAAAAAAA
DAAAAAAAA
EAAAAAAAA
FAAAAAAAA
GAAAAAAAA
HAAAAAAAA
IAAAAAAAA
KAAAAAAAA
LAAAAAAAA
MAAAAAAAA
NAAAAAAAA
PAAAAAAAA
QAAAAAAAA
RAAAAAAAA
SAAAAAAAA
TAAAAAAAA
VAAAAAAAA
WAAAAAAAA
YAAAAAAAA
```

Excluding characters B,J,O,U,X,Z, I was able to only repeat the PEPTIDE variable and output it to a file using this code

```
while [ $i -le 20 ]
do
    printf '%*s\n' "$len" | tr ' ' "$PEPTIDE_SEQ"  >> demo.txt
    i=$(( i+1 ))     # increments $i
done
```

how can I be able to simulate that block of code either using sed or awk? and then create another block of code but this time replacing the second letters then repeat the loop for the third block replacing the third letters and so forth.

Comment: Could you supply a sample of your input file and what you want ouputted from that input file?  That will help determine a solution.

Comment: I do not use an input file i just take the value of the PEPTIDE variable then sort and modify it, ideally i want the file i output to, to look this:

AAAAAAAAA 
CAAAAAAAA
DAAAAAAAA 
EAAAAAAAA 
FAAAAAAAA 
GAAAAAAAA 
HAAAAAAAA 
IAAAAAAAA
KAAAAAAAA 
LAAAAAAAA 
MAAAAAAAA 
NAAAAAAAA 
PAAAAAAAA 
QAAAAAAAA 
RAAAAAAAA 
SAAAAAAAA 
TAAAAAAAA 
VAAAAAAAA 
WAAAAAAAA 
YAAAAAAAA




AAAAAAAAC
AAAAAAAAD
AAAAAAAAE
AAAAAAAAF
AAAAAAAAG
AAAAAAAAH
AAAAAAAAI
AAAAAAAAK
AAAAAAAAL
AAAAAAAAM
AAAAAAAAN
AAAAAAAAP

Till Y on the last line..but also modifying other lines like that.

Comment: I'm afraid your script doesn't print anything but 20 `AAAAAAAAA`...

Comment: Please don't put updates in the comments. Out then in the Question. And use the `{}`  formatting button to show your blocks of data and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

pep="AAAAAAAA"

pos=1
while [ "$pos" -le "${#pep}" ]; do
    for aa in A C D E F G H I K L M N P Q R S T V W X Y
    do
        printf '%s%s%s\n' "${pep:0:pos-1}" "$aa" "${pep:pos}"
    done
    pos=$(( pos + 1 ))
done
```

The outer `while` loop steps through the positions in the given peptide sequence, and for each position the valid amino acid codes are put into the peptide one by one at that position (this uses substring expansion of the part of the peptide up to the relevant position, inserts the altered amino acid, and then does another substring expansion for the tail end of the peptide).

Comment: Thank you, this works when I run the script on windows but when I run it in Linux Ubuntu 18.04 I get a bad substitution error. Also is it possible that after each block I skip 2 lines before starting to iterate the next block?

Comment: @Morena Are you running the script with `bash` on Ubuntu? It requires that you run it with `bash`. To output on empty line, just insert `echo ""` in the script after the line that increments the variable `pos`.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Your spec is not TOO clear. How far would

```
awk -vPS="$PEPTIDE_SEQ" -vLEN=$len -vXCLI="B,J,O,U,X,Z" '
BEGIN   {PS = substr (PS, 2)     
         for (n=split (XCLI, T, ","); n; n--) XCL[T[n]]
         for (i=65; i<=90; i++) {C = sprintf ("%c", i)
                                 if (!(C in XCL)) printf "%s%s ", C, PS
                                }
         printf RS
        }
'
AAAAAAAAA CAAAAAAAA DAAAAAAAA EAAAAAAAA FAAAAAAAA GAAAAAAAA HAAAAAAAA IAAAAAAAA KAAAAAAAA LAAAAAAAA MAAAAAAAA NAAAAAAAA PAAAAAAAA QAAAAAAAA RAAAAAAAA SAAAAAAAA TAAAAAAAA VAAAAAAAA WAAAAAAAA YAAAAAAAA
```

get you?

**EDIT:** Rereading the spec after having read your comment, I came up with

```
awk -vPS="$PEPTIDE_SEQ" -vXCL="B,J,O,U,X,Z" '
BEGIN   {for (i=65; i<=90; i++) if (!(index(XCL, S = sprintf ("%c", i)))) print C[++n] = S, n
         for (i=1; i<=length(PS); i++)  {for (j=1; j<=n; j++) print substr (PS, 1, i-1) C[j] substr (PS, i+1)
                                         print ""
                                        }
        }
'
```

Does this fit your needs? Pls be aware that you only need to specify the chars-to-be-excluded, not all the "good" chars with the "bad" ones missing.

Comment: Thanks, it works but it only outputs a single block, I want it to continue editing the PEPTIDE_SEQ until the last character each time outputting a new modified block

Comment: Edited in a correction due to your comment...

Comment: Thank you mate, your solution works like a charm too, but I can only choose one answer.